# Mutliple Has_Many relation to same model but different lists

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am struggeling with setting up a a ONE TO MANY relation, in the way, that the parent object has 3 different relations to the child object.
The child can be in only 1 of these 3 relations to the parent.

I have the feeling, that I mixed it up a little, would be great full, if anybody can bring some light into this topic, what the best practice approach would be to setup these relations. 
I am relatively new to rails. Cheers

My Migration

```
add_reference :child_elements, :child_list_a, foreign_key: { to_table: :parent_elements }

add_reference :child_elements, :child_list_b, foreign_key: { to_table: :parent_elements }

add_reference :child_elements, :child_list_c, foreign_key: { to_table: :parent_elements }
```

Classes:

```rb
Child:
belongs_to :child_list_a, class_name: "ParentElement"
belongs_to :child_list_b, class_name: "ParentElement"
belongs_to :child_list_c, class_name: "ParentElement"


Parent:

has_many :child_elements_a, inverse_of: "child_list_a"
has_many :child_elements_b, inverse_of: "child_list_b"
has_many :child_elements_c, inverse_of: "child_list_c"
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what setup you are aiming for here. The `Parent` has 3 separate sets of `Child` associations, but they cannot overlap? And each `Child` must have 3 `Parent`s? (or are these associations optional)?

Comment: Anyway, once you've clarified the rules regarding these associations.... A cleaner setup would be to use a JOINS table, e.g. `parents_childs`. The table can have 3 columns: `parent_id` `child_id`, and for example `list_name` which is either `"a"`, `"b"` or `"c"`.

Comment: You can then do `has_many :child_elements_a, class_name: 'Child', through: :parents_childs, -> { where(list_name: 'A') }`, and you can define all the necessary database constraints and/or rails validations on the JOIN table, to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  Each child needs exacatly ONE Parent. The Child might be in the Parents A B or C list, but not in A and B -> Only one relation to the parent - I Hope this makes it cleared. Anyway thanks, I think your proposed solution does exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: @TomLord I can not accept you answer, as it is a comment it seems.